MyBatis mappers configuration
https://github.com/ChileKasoka/demospring
How do I resolve this error I keep getting. I have a mapper interface called called 'demoMapper', and I also have manually configured myBatis to initialize the bean files when the project runs.
Annotation-specified bean name 'demoMapper' for bean class [com.example.demo.repository.mapper.DemoMapper] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
mybatisconfig
I have tried creating the MyBatisConfig file with the following code snippet
package com.example.demo.config;


@Configuration
public class MyBatisConfig {

    private final SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;

    public MyBatisConfig(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        this.sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFactoryBean<DemoMapper> demoMapper() {
        MapperFactoryBean<DemoMapper> factoryBean = new MapperFactoryBean<>(DemoMapper.class);
        factoryBean.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}


Did you read the quick start guide? I'm not sure why you created MyBatisConfig. And there is no actual SQL statement defined for findAll(). Assuming you are a new user, I would suggest starting from a small working project and making small changes one by one. There is a template for spring-boot in this repo. Also see jpetstore-6 for more complex examples.


Annotation-specified bean name 'demoMapper' for bean class
[com.example.demo.repository.mapper.DemoMapper] conflicts with
existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class

Looks like you have another class or interface with name DemoMapper in this project. Could you check it, rename one of them and run project again?
Sorry, can't add comment because lack of reputation
